# Add custom tooltip to row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to customize my DataGrid to show a tooltip within the selected row, please see the mockup images below for a better idea of what I want to achieve.

**As it is at the moment** - Shows a single selected row:
[image]

**How I would like** - Shows the same row selected, now with tooltip:

[image]

- My DataGrid uses Binding to the ViewModel.
- Working with WPF & C# for Windows desktop.

I don't really have any idea how to achieve this, so I'm open to any suggestions at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [RowDetailsTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate.aspx).

Here is sample code:

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Background="Orange" Text="{Binding MoreInfo}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Please note that the DataGrid SelectionUnit must be set to FullRow for this to work. I initially had it set to Cell and didn't see anything.

Comment: From which object must the `MoreInfo` property be available? Is it the same object bound to the DataGrid which provides its rows?

Comment: @void.pointer If you are binding `ObservableCollection<T>` to the DataGrid ItemsSource so property `MoreInfo` should be defined in the object `T`.

Answer (score 27):

I use the `DataGrid.RowStyle` to set the tooltip.

My bound objects have a `ToolTipText` property which contains the content of the `ToolTip`.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipText}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: But a common problem with this is `tooltip` is getting out of `window` .. did you fixed that??

Comment: No, I do not know how to change this. For me this behavior of the `ToolTip` to be partially displayed outside of the containing window was ok.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way to add a tooltip on a row in a datagrid is the following.

Use the `LodingRow`Event and add your tooltip like this:

```
private void grdItemlogs_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row != null)
        {
            string toolTipText = "Your Tooltip string content"
            e.Row.ToolTip = toolTipText;

        }
    }
```