# How to display tooltip/pop-up of all data from database in datagrid in WPF MVVM C#

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, popup, tooltip

I have a datagrid on my usercontrol. Call it Students
And I have a database that pulls student information from a table, called Students.

In this table, there is:

```
ID int
Name varchar
Class varchar
Age int
Sport varchar
House varchar
```

now in the datagrid, the Name, Class and Age are displayed. How would i make a pop-up or tooltip display the other data (House and Sport) when the mouse is hovering over a row?

I am using MVVM principles, so no code behind. I know how to display data in MVVM standards, I just don't know how it would be that it displays the data for that specific row.

Example: if I have row - Mike, Class A, 13, how do I hover over Mike and display the Sport and House for him?

And would it be easier to use a pop-up:

```
<Popup Name="myPopup">
<TextBlock Text={Binding DataStud}>

</TextBlock>
</Popup>
```

or a tooltip in the datagrid:

```
<my:DataGrid ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipDisp}">
```

or, is it a row specific deal in the datagrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use RowDeatailsTemplate like [Add custom tooltip to row in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496142/add-custom-tooltip-to-row-in-datagrid) or you simply set the tooltip

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sport}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding House}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. however, should i change my Style TargetType to what datagrid i am using?

Comment: add this rowstyle to the datagrid where you want your tooltip. and if you want the tooltip only when hover the "Name" column/cell set the tooltip of the Name Column to the binding above